# Can I have a page in my Ruby on Rails app that doesn't use my application.html.erb template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates

I'm using `application.html.erb` in the `views/layouts` folder of my Ruby on Rails web app as a template. But there's one page in which I don't want the template to be used. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just do

```
render :layout => false
```

in the bottom of your action.

Comment: You can also specify another different layout to use with `render :layout => 'print'` for example.